# How to use a parent in Gradle across different projects?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am very deeply familiar with Maven, but I'm still catching up on my Gradle knowledge.

I would like to have a separate project which is a parent that contains the dependency/properties management and then use this from other projects. I'm not referring to sub-modules, but separate projects. In Maven this is possible, but I can't find a good example, of how to do this in Gradle. I assume the terminology is different.

Would somebody kindly show me an example of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @mark rotteveel: So, does this mean these init scripts can be deployed as separate artifacts?

Comment: See the first answer on the duplicate.